# Riemann Problem for Linear Hyperbolic Systems

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, hyperbolic-equations, cauchy-problem

I am following LeVeque's text "Numerical Methods for Conservation Laws" so I will be following his notation.

Suppose we are solving
$$u_t + Au_x = 0.$$
where $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times m}$. By diagonalizing $A = R \Lambda R^{-1}$ and setting $v = R^{-1}u$, the solution to the above is
$$u(x,t) = \sum_{p=1}^m v_p(x-\lambda_pt, 0)r_p$$
where $r_p$ is the $p$th eigenvector.

Now for the actual Riemann problem, suppose we have our original PDE along with the initial data:
$$u(x,0) = \begin{cases} u_l &\quad x<0 \\ u_r &\quad x>0\end{cases}$$

The text claims we can decompose $u_l$ and $u_r$ as
$$u_l = \sum_{p=1}^m \alpha_p r_p \quad u_r = \sum_{p=1}^m \beta_br_p$$
my **first question** is why are we able to do this?

This leads to
$$v_p(x,0) = \begin{cases} \alpha_p &\quad x<0 \\ \beta_p &\quad x>0\end{cases}$$
and so
$$v_p(x,t) = \begin{cases} \alpha_p &\quad x-\lambda_pt<0 \\ \beta_p &\quad x-\lambda_pt>0\end{cases}$$

Next, he lets $P(x,t)$ be the maximum value of $p$ for which $x-\lambda_pt > 0$ so that
$$u(x,t) = \sum_{p=1}^{P(x,t)} \beta_p r_p + \sum_{P(x,t)+1}^m \alpha_p r_p$$
**My second question** is what is the motivation behind $P$ here? I am unable to see its role.

Next, he says across the $p$th characteristic the solution jumps with the jump given by
$$[u] = (\beta_p - \alpha_p)r_p$$
**My third question** is that I assume this is because we are jumping from one part of the discontinuity in the Riemann solution to the other, is this true?

Lastly, since $f(u) = Au$ we have
$$[f] = A[u] = A(\beta_p - \alpha_p)r_p = \lambda_p[u]$$
so that the solution $u(x,t)$ can be written in terms of these jumps as
$$u(x,t) = u_l + \sum_{\lambda_p < x/t} (\beta_p - \alpha_p)r_p = u_r - \sum_{\lambda_p \geq x/t} (\beta_p - \alpha_p)r_p$$
**My fourth question** is that I am unclear how he derives the above expression for $u(x,t)$ using the jump condition. How does one imply the other?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1.) Because the vectors $r_p$ form a basis, the eigen-basis of the eigen-decomposition.

2.) Along the way it must have been somehow justified that $A$ only has real eigenvalues, and that in the eigen-decomposition the eigenvalues are sorted in ascending order. Then $P$ separates which eigenvalues give a shock front to the left and which to the right of $(x,t)$

3.) Yes.

4.) This is just arithmetic manipulation with some geometric interpretation.
\begin{align}
u(x,t) &= \sum_{p=1}^{P(x,t)} \beta_p r_p + \sum_{p=P(x,t)+1}^m \alpha_p r_p
\\
&=\sum_{p=1}^{P(x,t)} (\beta_p-\alpha_p) r_p + \sum_{p=1}^m \alpha_p r_p
\\
&=\sum_{p:\,x-\lambda_pt>0} (\beta_p-\alpha_p) r_p + u_l
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks! I see so for (1) it is because the $p$th eigenvalue change once one crosses the $p$th characteristic? For (4) I see how one obtains the expressions geometrically, but in the text LeVeque says that the expressions are written in terms of these jumps. What was the point of calculating the jump $[f]$ if we do not use it explicitly? Is it just to check that the Rankine-Hugoniot condition is satisfied?